# How to use ngx-formly hideExpression to hide and display child elements based on parents value

Tags: angular, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I am new to angular formly

> I want to use formly to build a form for the following scenario:

1. there are three sibling elements
2. out of which two elements are dependant on the value of one sibling element which is radio button group. i.e I want to hide or display **basic** and **advance** form based on **recipientQueryOption**
3. I am using the JSON file to store schema so not able to write hide expression directly into the schema.

I tried using Extension for hiding expression but as I found that in Extension data available in the model is limited to the element where hide expression is written and its child elements and doesn't contain data for its parent element. as data for a parent is not available, I am not able to check the value of the radio button and not able to decide whether to hide an element or not.

> following is JSON schema:

```
{
    key: 'Recipients',
    fieldGroup: [{
            key: 'recipientQueryOption',
            type: 'radio',
            templateOptions: {
                required: true,
                options: [{
                        value: 'queryBuilder',
                        label: 'queryBuilder'
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'queryEditor',
                        label: 'queryEditor'
                    },
                ],
            },
            defaultValue: 'queryBuilder'
        },
        {
            key: "basic",
            fieldGroup: [{
                key: 'recipients',
                type: 'chips',
                templateOptions: {
                    label: 'Recipients',
                    placeholder: 'add recipients...',
                    required: true,
                }
            }],
            hideExpression: "hide_expression"
        },
        {
            key: "advance",
            fieldGroup: [{
                    key: 'recipients',
                    type: 'textarea',
                    templateOptions: {
                        label: 'Recipients',
                        placeholder: 'Enter Query',
                        required: true,
                    }
                },
                {
                    template: '<b>Note:</b> No validation is done on the queries submitted from the Query Editor tab.',
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You can display the using flag. Use since the value is appear enable flag.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf use this flag options

Comment: @Mokkasoru how to add ngIf in ngx-formlys' schema

Comment: Can you share me HTML file sample

Comment: there is no HTML file all the fields are rendered by ngx-formly based on above JSON.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-formly-ui-bootstrap?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html 
please check this link and set test boolean value .
<formly-form *ngIf="test"
          [form]="form"
          [model]="model"
          [fields]="fields">
        </formly-form>
  test:boolean=true;

Comment: the issue solved, https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/issues/2125#event-3096314415

Answer (score 0):

hideExpression: "field.parent.model. advance !== 'true/false'"

https://github.com/ngx-formly/ngx-formly/issues/2125

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).